# swift class init by telling which function to call

Tags: swift, function, class, init

I have a class cards which includes many variables and is used for cards in a board game.

Now some instances of cards should perform special actions.

My plan is to create different functions (in or outside the class) and tell the class which function to use at init.

But how to do this ?

```
class classCards {
var xy: Int
var whichFunction:  //what should i declare


init(number: Int, function: //what should i declare) {
    self.xy = number
    self.whichFunction = function
}

func letsDoIt() {
    whichFunction()
}

}
```

Comment: Just some unrelated notes: Swift class names should be UpperCamelCase. Your class name has the word "class" in it, which adds no value. We can see that it's a class. Also, your class name has "Cards", plural, even though it models a single card.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `typealias` for this to pass a function `closure` as parameter, observe the code below.

```
class classCards {
    typealias myFunction = () -> Void
    var xy : Int
    var whichFunction: myFunction


    init(number: Int, function: @escaping myFunction) {
        self.xy = number
        self.whichFunction = function
        letsDoIt()
    }

    func letsDoIt() {
        whichFunction()
    }
}
//Useage
func foo(){
    print("foo")
}
classCards(number: 10, function: foo)
```

Comment: I wouldn't both type aliasing somemthing as simple as `() -> Void`. It's just unnecessary abstraction. Also, it's probably useful to have a parameter that passes the card instance into the function.

Comment: ofc, he just ask on how he can pass a function. aliasing just for the delegate code :D

Comment: @Alexander The type alias is useful here. If, later, the signature needs to be changed, it is easier to update the one `typealias` instead of updating every use of the original signature.

Comment: @rmaddy Fair point!

Comment: Nevertheless I don't think involving typealias unnecessarily in what is clearly a very beginner-level question is pedagogically useful. It would be better to show simply how to pass, store, and call a function.

Comment: may you give an example of how to store a function? I only found examples where the function provided a result.

Comment: What do you mean by store ? , search if you can’t find anything post a question we might be able to understand what you need , but first search it and please explain to me more I might be able to help here

Comment: I am referring to matts comment "It would be better to show simply how to pass, store, and call a function".
I searched for this but only found answers how to store functions giving back a result.

Comment: I mean using the typealias works, thats great. I just thought if one could solve my problem without using typealias by using simpler stuff I would like to try this out

Comment: aah, @Andy that what i did in my answer is passing the function, store it in a variable , then use it

Comment: aliasing is the easier way and better far when you are into it, as @rmaddy said, you can remove typealias however and just use () -> Void as parameter type